# explanation of fromhex format in Python

Tags: python, arrays, format

I am looking at a Python code that has a line like this:

```
the_text = bytearray.fromhex('{:0256x}'.format(random.getrandbits(16*8)))
```

Can someone explain the right hand expression, on what it does? I assume it is supposed to generate some random data, but what `{:0256x}` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{:0256x}` part is interpreted by the `.format()` method.

It's replaced by the value of the parameter passed to `.format()`, and the `:0256x` tells format to take a numerical value and represent it as hexadecimal, using at least 256 positions.

For example `f'{100:02x}'` would print as `64`. `f'{100:04x}'` as `0064`. `f'{100:01x}'` would still print as `64`, because it doesn't fit in a single digit hexadecimal.

In your case, whatever the value of `random.getrandbits(16*8)` turns out to be, will be turned into a (at least) 256 character hexadecimal representation, which `.fromhex()` then turns into a byte array. It'll never be more, as `random.getrandbits(16*8)` would only generate values that can be shown using 256 positions hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

`{:0256x}` means if the he`x`adecimal string representation of your number is less than `256` characters, it will be padded with `0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accepted the other answer as it was more complete. But still I upvoted yours as well.